# Manager isn't accessible via model instances

Tags: python, django, django-models, instance, django-managers

I'm trying to get model objects instance in another one and I raise this error :

> Manager isn't accessible via topic instance

Here's my model :

```
class forum(models.Model):
    # Some attributs

class topic(models.Model):
    # Some attributs

class post(models.Model):
    # Some attributs

    def delete(self):
        forum = self.topic.forum
        super(post, self).delete()
        forum.topic_count = topic.objects.filter(forum = forum).count()
```

Here's my view :

```
def test(request, post_id):
    post = topic.objects.get(id = int(topic_id))
    post.delete()
```

And I get :

```
post.delete()
forum.topic_count = topic.objects.filter(forum = forum).count()
Manager isn't accessible via topic instances
```

Comment: you need to use Topic (class name) to access objects (Manager). as mentioned in Django documentation (Managers are accessible only via model classes, rather than from model instances, to enforce a separation between “table-level” operations and “record-level” operations.)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The error in question is caused when you try to access the `Manager` of a model through an instance of the model. You have used *lower case* class names. This makes it hard to say if the error is caused by an instance accessing the `Manager` or not. Since other scenarios that can cause this error are unknown I am proceeding on the assumption that you have somehow mixed up the `topic` variable so that you end up pointing to an instance of the `topic` model instead of the class.

This line is the culprit:

```
forum.topic_count = topic.objects.filter(forum = forum).count()
#                   ^^^^^
```

You have to use:

```
forum.topic_count = Topic.objects.filter(forum = forum).count()
#                   ^^^^^
#                   Model, not instance.
```

What is going wrong? `objects` is a `Manager` available at the class level, not to the instances. See the [documentation for retrieving objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) for details. Money quote:

> `Managers` are accessible ***only*** via model classes, rather than from model instances, to enforce a separation between "table-level" operations and "record-level" operations.

(Emphasis added)

**Update**

See the comments from @Daniel below. It is a good idea (nay, you MUST :P) to use title case for class names. For instance `Topic` instead of `topic`. Your class names cause some confusion whether you are referring to an instance or a class. Since the `Manager isn't accessible via <model> instances` is very specific I am able to offer a solution.The error may not be so self evident always.

Comment: However, `topic` does appear to be the actual model class, and not an instance according to the code he provided.

Comment: @Daniel: true. And yet the error `Manager isn't accessible via Foo instances` is only possible when you try to access a `Manager` using an instance. See the source code: http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/db/models/manager.py

Comment: Indeed, perhaps another reason (other than "it's best practice") not to use lowercase letters for class names :)  It would appear he's potentially using `topic` as a local instance variable and blowing away the reference to the class.

Comment: You should have used `topic.model_class().objects`

Comment: You could also use `topic.__class__.objects`. It would seem `model_class()` mentioned by @Nimo above doesn't work

Comment: Ignoring the obvious issues with the class names, @sleepycal provides the best answer if you're genuinely trying to access the manage based on an instance.

Comment: An alternative would be `topic._meta.model.objects`

Answer (score 77):

```
topic.__class__.objects.get(id=topic_id)
```

Comment: Works as of Django v1.10.

Comment: This `__class__` works better for methods within abstract models as well, as we don't know the actual name of the descendant class.  In this situation, I used `self.__class__.objects.get`

Comment: Works awesome on a `models.py` model. `def get_object(self): return self.__class__.objects.get(...)`. Using this for a `GenericForeignKey`.

Answer (score 33):

For django < 1.10

```
topic._default_manager.get(id=topic_id)
```

Though you should not use it like this. The _default_manager and _base_manager are private, so it's recomended to use them only if you're inside the Topic model, like when you want to use the Manager in a proprietary function let's say:

```
class Topic(Model):
.
.
.
    def related(self)
        "Returns the topics with similar starting names"
        return self._default_manager.filter(name__startswith=self.name)

topic.related() #topic 'Milan wins' is related to:
# ['Milan wins','Milan wins championship', 'Milan wins by one goal', ...]
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer was just what I'd been searching for.  I wish I could up vote more than once.  My use-case for this is when you're adding functionality to an abstract model, where you won't know (at this level) what the final model class is called.

Comment: Or use `topic.__class__.objects.get(id=topic_id)`.

Comment: This is an old answer, but as of Django v1.10 I don't see these private methods anymore. However, `self.__class__.objects` does the trick per your other answer.

Answer (score 12):

Could also be caused by a pair of parantheses too much, e.g.

```
ModelClass().objects.filter(...)
```

instead of the correct

```
ModelClass.objects.filter(...)
```

Happens to me sometimes when bpython (or an IDE) automatically adds parantheses.

The result, of course, is the same - you have an instance instead of a class.

Answer (score 0):

if topic were a ContentType instance (which it is not), this would have worked:

```
topic.model_class().objects.filter(forum = forum)
```

Comment: [`model_class()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType.model_class) is a method of the `ContentType` model. Other model instances, including `topic`, do not have a `model_class` method.

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread the question. I was trying to solve a seemingly-similar question...

Answer (score 0):

I just had an issue similar to this error.  And looking back at your code it seems that it could be your issue too.  I think your issue is that your comparing "id" to "int(topic_id)" and topic_id is not set.

```
def test(request, post_id):
    post = topic.objects.get(id = int(topic_id))
    post.delete()
```

I'm guessing your code should use "post_id" not "topic_id"

```
def test(request, post_id):
    post = topic.objects.get(id = int(post_id))
    post.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via CustomUser instances

When I accessed `Manager` with `request.user.objects` as shown below:

```py
"views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    print(request.user.objects)
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Comment: The `objects` manager is accessible at class level and not at instance level. You cannot do `request.user.objects`. Instead use `User.objects`. Not sure what you are trying to print here anyway.. `objects` is the default name of the manager. Why print manager?

Answer (score 0):

This is a old topic but if anyone encountering this issue, consider checking your view method, you may used model methods in a model class instance, in Django, you should use model methods directly on to model itself but not on the class instances, so with examples:

this will raise an error

```py
model = Model.objects.get(unique_id)
model.objects.do_something()
```

and you should do

```py
model = get_object_or_404(ModelClass, unique_id)
model.objects.do_something()
```