# Django - Update User/Account Management

Tags: python, django, django-forms, view

I am trying to update my user account info through a form. I have the form ok which just displays a password/email field and cleans the email field. I am having a problem with my views. This is the error I get: Manager isn't accessible via User instances.
This is my views: my_account function.

```
def my_account(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyAccountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = user.objects.get(username=username),
            password = user.set_password('password2'),
            email = forms.cleaned_data['email']
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = MyAccountForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
    })
    return render_to_response(
        'my_account.html',
        variables
    )
```

Comment: this is, however, an exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874187/manager-isnt-accessible-via-model-instances. Please try simply searching your error message before posting a new question.

Comment: I did and obviously that wasn't my only issue. I always look up my own errors first but sometimes thats not always helpful.

Answer (score 2):

where you have

`user.objects.get`

you want

`User.objects.get`

`objects` is the manager referred to in the error message, and `user` is the instance referred to (an instance of `User`, the actual class)

Comment: ok did that now it says username is not defined so i added username to the paramaters next to request and to my variables with forms but now i get the error: my_account() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Wow, there's a whole host of problems here. Sounds like you need to 1: read your error messages, 2: learn more about Django, 3: proofread your code. Let's tackle these: 1. "`my_account() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`"= you changed `my_account` so it takes 2 params, but you're still only giving it 1 (presumably the request). 2: As far as I'm aware, all the data in Django forms is serialized into the `POST` field in the `request`; variables are not passed individually. To access `username` you should not have added it as a new param, but extracted it from the request.

Comment: 3: look at your code. You *haven't* defined `username` anywhere (ties back into problem #1-- not actually reading your error messages). You just use it in the `get` call. You need to actually extract it from the request before you can pass it to anything else!

Comment: I was trying to extract it from the request for instance user = request.user(user = User.username), I know that is not correct but I could not figure out how to call it. The reason I added it as a parameter was because I did it in a previous view page- user_page and it worked correctly so I wanted to see if that would help. I am still very new to this so I'm sorry I don't fully understand everything yet. Also, I do read my error messages but sometimes I do not fully understand the issue. I knew it was having a problem with username and that I hadn't called it anywhere I just didn't know where.

Comment: as an example, look at how you're extracting `email`. That's probably the way you want to extract `username`. Though now that I'm rereading your code, why are you even doing this? You already have `user` from when you did `user = request.user`. Also, this snippet `user = request.user(user = User.username)` is wrong for a lot of reasons: 1. in `request.user`, `user` is a property, not a function, 2: you're comparing `user` to `username` in that clause, 3: as I said above, `User` is a class name, not an instance name, and as such will have no `.username` property.

Comment: At any rate, I think since you already have `user`, you should just delete the line where you're reassigning it and be good to go.

Comment: My professor wants us to call the username so how would I extract that from request.user?

Comment: What does "call the username" mean? And user is an instance of User, so it has all of the properties of any other instance of User... like username...